# How to change background color of UIcollectionViewCell on tap using swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
}
```

Why it takes about 45 seconds to show background color when I tap on cell? Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: you have no issue , your code work normal no delay, just share what you have may be your issue not in this part

Comment: Nope all others functions working fine but when I use "didSelectItem" for changing background it delay. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: i test my self and its work

Comment: can I update my question with all coding? @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: yes you can or send it as link

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dkswe21/ecbcabd3aeb68ee29409d8f8fe58a5da @AbdelahadDarwish

Answer (score 2):

Do this on your class extending UICollectionViewCell:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.black : UIColor.blue
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove  this line

```
 self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

To be like that :

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        }


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
```

Comment: did not work for me still same problem @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: how this i just test there

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as well and by this you can do customisation with time

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    {
           cell.backgroundColor = .green

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.2 , execute:
        {
              cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        })
    }
}
```